# ArcObjects bug in OID field duplication while duplicating feature class?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, features

I have a shapefile with a column of type esriFieldTypeOID with the name FID and numbers from 0 to 5 (the first odd think is that ArcMap does not show a * next to the column name in the table view even if its of the OID type)

After duplicating the whole FeatureClass I have my FID column in the new FeatureClass but this time I have the numbers from 1 to 6!

If I use another file were I have the number from 1 to 6 I have also 1 to 6 in the copy.
According to the doc the OID is an integer and not null, therefore the 0 to 5 should not be a problem.

Thats the code I use:

```
// get FeatureClassName for input
        IDataset inDataset = inFeatureClass as IDataset;
        IFeatureClassName inFeatureClassName = inDataset.FullName as IFeatureClassName;
        IWorkspace inWorkspace = inDataset.Workspace;

        // get WorkSpaceName for output
        IDataset outDataset = outWorkspace as IDataset;
        IWorkspaceName outWorkspaceName = outDataset.FullName as IWorkspaceName;

        // Create new FeatureClassName
        IFeatureClassName outFeatureClassName = new FeatureClassNameClass();
        // Assign it a name and a workspace
        IDatasetName datasetName = outFeatureClassName as IDatasetName;
        datasetName.Name = newName == String.Empty ? (inFeatureClassName as IDatasetName).Name : newName;
        datasetName.WorkspaceName = outWorkspaceName;

        // Check for field conflicts.
        IFieldChecker fieldChecker = new FieldCheckerClass();
        IFields inFields = inFeatureClass.Fields;
        IFields outFields;
        IEnumFieldError enumFieldError;
        fieldChecker.InputWorkspace = inWorkspace;
        fieldChecker.ValidateWorkspace = outWorkspace;
        fieldChecker.Validate(inFields, out enumFieldError, out outFields);
        // Check enumFieldError for field naming confilcts

        //Convert the data.
        IFeatureDataConverter featureDataConverter = new FeatureDataConverterClass();
        featureDataConverter.ConvertFeatureClass(inFeatureClassName, null, null,
        outFeatureClassName, null, outFields, "", 100, 0);

        IFeatureWorkspace pFeatureWS = (IFeatureWorkspace)outWorkspace;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of searching I found the solution [ESRI knowledge base](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37480).

> When a geodatabase feature class is exported or converted to a new geodatabase feature class, or when a geodatabase table is exported or converted to a new geodatabase table, the records are renumbered sequentially starting at 1 in the output feature class or table.

And they also described the problem of this behavior.

> It is important to be aware of these behaviors when selecting fields for joining or relating tables. If a shapefile were to be joined to a feature class using the FID and OBJECTID fields, the shapefile record with FID = 0 would not be matched to a record in the feature class, as there is no record in a feature class with OBJECTID = 0.